# How to add an event outside the Slick after clicking on the dot marker

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

I use a standard slider slider, and I want to add an event outside the slider itself but on the same page. I tried to catch the event in different ways:

```
    $("ul.slick-dots li button").click(function() {
        $('.map_animation').toggleClass('map_animation2');
    });
```

or

```
    $(".main .big-slider-sec .slick-dots li button").click(function() {
        $('.map_animation').toggleClass('map_animation2');
    });
```

or

```
    $("#slick-slide01:button").click(function() {
        $('.map_animation').toggleClass('map_animation2');
    });
```

or

```
    $("#slick-slide00").find("button").click(function() {
        $('.map_animation').toggleClass('map_animation2');
    });
```

or

```
    $("#slick-slide00").children("button").click(function() {
        $('.map_animation').toggleClass('map_animation2');
    });
```

but none of this has worked, and my event does not happen by clicking on the slider markers

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of things, it turned out like this:

```
        $('.big-slider-sec').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
        $("#slick-slide01").click(function() {
            $('.map_animation').toggleClass('map_animation2');
        });
    });
```

maybe someone needs it